# How to set a Telerik grid to allowing vertical scrolling

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, telerik

I have a gridview and I with a normal windows form I can set `overflow-y:scroll;` and it allow me to scroll all the rows and keeping the same format. When I try it with a Telerik grid I get a very similar result but the formatting does not stay the same. I set the grid to 950px and and the first rows are the correct color format  after those immediate few the rest are the same as my page backgroud.

example asp:
Blue,
White,
Blue,
White,
Is correct

Telerik:
Blue,
White,
Blue,
White,
Background Color,
White,
Background Color,
White

Is there a property I need to set to allow all the rows in the table to be the same format other than what I already have? Or any other ideas on how to fix this will be greatly appreciated!

```
<form id="form1" style="background-color:Black; overflow-y:scroll; height:950px"" runat="server">
<div>

    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" Runat="server">
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>

    <telerik:RadGrid ID="MissingPluGrid" runat="server" Width="900px" 
        BackColor="#0099CC" Height="1000px">
    </telerik:RadGrid>
    <br />
    <br />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
  <ClientSettings>
<Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True"></Scrolling>
</ClientSettings>
```

For your reference - http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/scrolling/scrolling/defaultcs.aspx